# How to "cd $variable" when the variable tries to add "\" before spaces (path contain spaces)?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, cd-command

My bash script registers its own path so it can return to its own folder after doing a `cd` somewhere (kinda if it explores a different forest and is able to relocate its house).

And if the path have spaces, I've used `sed` to add `\` before every space.

But when using `cd $SCRIPTPATH` to this variable:

> ./newsed.sh: 11: cd: can't cd to /media/daniell/B/bkp/ST500LM012\

Source:
newsed.sh:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -e

tmp="$( cd -- "$(dirname "$0")" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; pwd -P )"
SCRIPTPATH="$(echo "$tmp" | sed 's/ /\\ /g')"

echo "$SCRIPTPATH"

ls
cd
ls
cd $SCRIPTPATH
ls
```

`echo $SCRIPTPATH` produces a normal path (`/media/daniell/B/bkp/ST500LM012\ HN-M500MBB\ Dat/0/ok/Pendrive/flshdrive/0.Floflis-DNA/layers/soil`) that I can manually copy and cd into it, and works; but when `cd`'ing directly to the variable (`cd $SCRIPTPATH`) it crashes right after the `\`.

Comment: *"And if the path have spaces, I've used sed to add \ before every space."* you can avoid the need to do that altogether by quoting the variable expansion properly ex. `cd "$variable"`

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you, the output have improved. But: `./newsed.sh: 11: cd: can't cd to /media/daniell/B/bkp/ST500LM012\ HN-M500MBB\ Dat/0/ok/Pendrive/flshdrive/0.Floflis-DNA/layers/soil` ?

Comment: Are you still escaping the spaces with backslashes with sed? If so - don't.

Comment: @steeldriver Gotcha! Thanks a lot. If you turn your comments into a answer, I'll mark it as correct/best answer.

Comment: Don't bother with escaping spaces, simply quote the variable expansion: `cd "$tmp"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes around variables to prevent spaces from being treated as delimiters in the shell, i.e.

```
cd "$SCRIPTPATH"
```

will work.